# How do I count duplicate values as 1, with multiple columns and conditions

Tags: excel, database

I have a database similar to the attached picture. It is automatically updated every week. Each store has a unique ID, sells a number of products, and each product is on sale for a specific time frame.

My goal is to create a single formula that can count stores that 'Pass' our policy (**with duplicate counts only one time**) and have a number of products sold **greater than 1.**
P/S: A single store with one product may appear in many rows, as each row represents that product's time frame. Therefore, the formula has to also take those duplications into account."

[image]

I have search a lot of ways but fail to find any formula that works. As the database is updated weekly, I need a formula that can automatically count number of "Pass" store with number of products > 1. As it would take too much step and time to count manually.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, add data example easy to copy with [Markdown Tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Also, add expected output

Comment: If a store has a product rejected and a product with Pass is the store Passed or Reject?

Comment: Would 1142237 Product B count as two products because the duplicates occur in different time frames?

Comment: Hi, if a store has Pass and Reject products, that store is counted as Pass if there is at least 1 product classified as Pass

Comment: To answer this question - "Would 1142237 Product B count as two products because the duplicates occur in different time frames?" ==> This is what I want to solve, I only want to count ID 1142237 only 1 time, even if it has mutiple "Passed" products or just 1 "Passes" product but sold at diferent time frame. Hope this clear any question